# C1356: unable to find mspdbcore.dll

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to "compile without linking" a code meant to be used as multithreaded .dll in future. I am using VS 2019 for the same. Here is the command that I have used:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX64\x86\cl.exe" /c /MD "C:\SpiceOpus\bin\ifspec.c"
```

This returns the following response:

> ifspec.c
> c1: fatal error C1356: unable to find mspdbcore.dll

This file is however present in the following 3 locations in my system as confirmed by using dir /s mspdbcore.dll :

A)

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE

B)

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX64\x64

C)

> Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX86\x86

Thus, I would like to know how to instruct the compiler for the presence of these files and then use them. I have tried using /l option for doing this as shown :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX64\x86\cl.exe" /c /MD /L "C:\SpiceOpus\bin\ifspec.c"
```

But it says :

> cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/L'

Please feel free to correct / suggest an alternative path. Kindly consider me as layman in coding things. I am in EE with not much experience in these coding stuff. Thank You.

--------------------------- Regarding PATH-----------------

1. Using SET command in developer cmd prompt showed this after installation for PATH variable:

> Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\Tools;

2. If one uses cl command in Administrator developer command prompt after this, it doesn't recognize it. However, if one uses the following code:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe"
```

This evokes the following response:

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.20.27525 for x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
> usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]

3. I tried to use SET command to modify the PATH using

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe;%PATH%
```

PATH gets modified but using cl command (in administrator developer cmd prompt of course ) again says that it's not recognized.

4. I have already repaired the installation for BuildTools using its installer. cl.exe works for sure or how else do you get the response given in point 2,5.  Please let me know why cl doesn't work but writing the command in point 2 gives results? Secondly, the modified PATH variable gets restored to the original one after every reboot. How do I avoid this?
5. So in summary this is where I am stuck now: I have figured out that the following code seems to work partly :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include" /I "C:\SpiceOpus\source\include" "C:\SpiceOpus\bin\cfunc.c" /c /MD "C:\SpiceOpus\bin\cfunc.c"
```

But it just says it is generating code........ I can't find any object file from it.

Comment: Run those commands at a [developer prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2019). See for example [Walkthrough: Compiling a Native C++ Program on the Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160).

Comment: These commands were executed on developer command prompt only.

Comment: You should have B) or C) set in the PATH at the developer cmd prompt. Also, there is no need to specify the full path to `cl`. In fact, that can cause problems if it doesn't match the environment.

Comment: Thanks @dxiv for your kind suggestions.  If one uses cl.exe /c /MD "filename" directly, it says cl.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command.  If one uses "cl.exe with path name of B or C" /c /MD "Filename" then it says > C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vcruntime.h': No such file or directory  . This vcruntime.h does exist for sure. So if one attempts to add its directory to include search path using "cl.exe with path name of B or C" /I <directory of vcruntime.h> then it says " cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename " . Basically this is what is the problem.

Comment: "*it says cl.exe is not recognized*" That can only mean you are not running the real developer cmd prompt, or something is broken in your VS installation. It is kind of pointless to proceed before you figure out and fix this basic problem. I suggest you try the steps from the links in my first comment and track down where what you get diverges from the expected behavior.

Comment: @dxiv I have been using visual C developer command prompt for sure, as you can gauge from the codes that i have shared earlier. What I was not doing is not running it as administrator. But even that doesn't solve the issue. I

Comment: Compiling at the VS dev prompt does not require elevation or admin rights. If it doesn't work for you, then there is something very broken with your VS environment. What does `path` show at the dev prompt?

Comment: @dxiv I have edited the main content giving details on PATH. I have repaired the installation already. Yes, I didn't install all the optional things. I installed Windows10 SDK, Text Template Transformation, C++ core features, MSVCv14.2..Buildtools, C++ Build tools core features, Windows Universal C runtime. I also have VS professional with following installed additionally: Roslyn compiler, MSBuild. Do I need anything extra for making cl command work ?  I want the minimum installation to make it work since I wouldn't  be using it often.

Comment: The PATH is missing several C/C++ related paths. It sounds like you cherry-picked "individual components" to install instead of "workloads", and you guessed wrong about what's optional vs. required. What you need to build native Windows C/C++ apps is the "desktop development with C++" workload.

Comment: Yes but it has lot many optionals. Can You please let me know why does cl.exe work when full path is given ? Can we set the missing paths using SET command ? In particular, please do let me know which of the optionals do i need to install. I don't need all of them for sure, because cl.exe is already there. Just need a way to set the PATH to it.

Comment: @dxiv Secondly, I am using Build Tools installer because I want to work with command line. In that installer there is nothing like "desktop development with C++" workload.  There is C++ Build tools workload which has options of c++ make tools, testing tools core feature, c++ address sanitizer, ATL, MFC, CLI. Clang tools. Can you please tell me which one of them is required ?

Comment: Just because you have a `cl.exe` somewhere on disk doesn't mean you have a working environment. You'll need to figure out the right PATH with all the required components, then the same for INCLUDE, LIB and so on. As for mixing VS with the standalone build tools, I am not familiar with that setup and, honestly, I don't see the point. The usual way is to install the desktop C/C++ workload, then you can do it all at the command line in the dev prompt without ever opening the IDE if you so prefer. If that's not what you are looking for then you should make that plenty clear in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As rightly commented by @dxiv i was wrong in cherry-picking during installation of MS Build Tools. So the suggestion given by @dxiv solves the issue and i no longer get the error mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when trying to run dumpbin.exe from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x86` with either the /HEADERS or /ALL flags on a 64 bit machine.

The fix was to `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64` and then `dumpbin /HEADERS "c:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10\pgAdmin 4\bin\libpq.dll"` worked.

Since this was at the top of the search list for this error message, I wanted to report the fix.

Answer (score 1):

using Visual Studio Installer, you'll want to:

1. Click "Modify" on your existing Visual Studio 2019/2022 install.
2. Select "Individual Components" on the next screen
3. In the search box, put in "2017"
4. Check the box labeled "MSVC v141 - VS 2017 C++ x64/x86 Spectre-mitigated libs"
5. click Install

[image]

After installation completes, you can re-run your `cargo install` or whatever gave you that error message and it should work. I didn't have to reboot or re-open a terminal/command prompt, it just worked once I installed.